# parsing of a string containing an array

Tags: c#, string, list

I'd like to convert string containing recursive array of strings to an array of depth one.

Example:

```
StringToArray("[a, b, [c, [d, e]], f, [g, h], i]") == ["a", "b", "[c, [d, e]]", "f", "[g, h]", "i"]
```

Seems quite simple. But, I come from functional background and I'm not that familiar with .NET Framework standard libraries, so every time (I started from scratch like 3 times) I end up just plain ugly code. My latest implementation is [here](https://github.com/egon-sim/egon_gui/blob/fff91812e922a23c5b76cdb4939f786f3926a4d6/EGON_cs_API/Lib.cs#L26). As you see, it's ugly as hell.

So, what's the C# way to do this?

Comment: +1 for a challenging problem. However, I think this is typically for codereview: codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ojlovecd has a good answer, using Regular Expressions.
However, his answer is overly complicated, so here's my similar, simpler answer.

```
public string[] StringToArray(string input) {
    var pattern = new Regex(@"
        \[
            (?:
            \s*
                (?<results>(?:
                (?(open)  [^\[\]]+  |  [^\[\],]+  )
                |(?<open>\[)
                |(?<-open>\])
                )+)
                (?(open)(?!))
            ,?
            )*
        \]
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    // Find the first match:
    var result = pattern.Match(input);
    if (result.Success) {
        // Extract the captured values:
        var captures = result.Groups["results"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
        return captures;
    }
    // Not a match
    return null;
}
```

Using this code, you will see that `StringToArray("[a, b, [c, [d, e]], f, [g, h], i]")` will return the following array: `["a", "b", "[c, [d, e]]", "f", "[g, h]", "i"]`.

For more information on the balanced groups that I used for matching balanced braces, take a look at [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition).

**Update**:
As per the comments, if you want to also balance quotes, here's a possible modification.  (Note that in C# the `"` is escaped as `""`)  I also added descriptions of the pattern to help clarify it:

```
    var pattern = new Regex(@"
        \[
            (?:
            \s*
                (?<results>(?:              # Capture everything into 'results'
                    (?(open)                # If 'open' Then
                        [^\[\]]+            #   Capture everything but brackets
                        |                   # Else (not open):
                        (?:                 #   Capture either:
                            [^\[\],'""]+    #       Unimportant characters
                            |               #   Or
                            ['""][^'""]*?['""] #    Anything between quotes
                        )  
                    )                       # End If
                    |(?<open>\[)            # Open bracket
                    |(?<-open>\])           # Close bracket
                )+)
                (?(open)(?!))               # Fail while there's an unbalanced 'open'
            ,?
            )*
        \]
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution. :)

Comment: Thanks, hope I didn't steal your thunder :)

Comment: Certainly not. There is only discussion and improvement. :)

Comment: Your solution is beautiful. I finally managed to find time and study it, and it really is fantastic. Only one problem: now I'd like strings also to be preserved as atomic entities even if they contain lists (so: "[a, \"b, [c, d]\", e]" => ["a", "b, [c, d]", "e"]), but quotes do not have distinction between opening and closing quote, so balancing groups do not work. Do you have an elegant solution to this also? :-)

Comment: Balanced quotes -- way to throw a wrench into the engine!  [I did this in JavaScript recently](https://gist.github.com/1349099), but that solution used Regex as a parsing engine, so it wasn't a pure Regex solution.  It might be interesting to take a look.

Comment: I added to my answer my attempt at balanced quotes.

Answer (score 2):

with Regex, it can solve your problem:

```
static string[] StringToArray(string str)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\[(.*)\]$");
    Match match = reg.Match(str);
    if (!match.Success)
        return null;
    str = match.Groups[1].Value;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    reg = new Regex(@"\[[^\[\]]*(((?'Open'\[)[^\[\]]*)+((?'-Open'\])[^\[\]]*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))\]");
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    int index = 0;
    str = reg.Replace(str, m =>
    {
        string temp = "ojlovecd" + (index++).ToString();
        dic.Add(temp, m.Value);
        return temp;
    });
    string[] result = str.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        string s = result[i].Trim();
        if (dic.ContainsKey(s))
            result[i] = dic[s].Trim();
        else
            result[i] = s;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I also think Regex is the way to , but this won't work, because you need to capture "balanced" braces.

Comment: @ScottRippey Hi, Scott, I modified my code, have a try please.

Comment: That looks good. Needs some clean up, but I'll assume it works :)  For anyone else interested in these "balancing groups", especially for balanced brace matching, you should take a look at [Microsoft's documentation on "Balancing Group Definitions".](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would just write this method in an F# assembly as its probably much easier.  If you look at the `JavaScriptSerializer` implementation in C# (with a decompiler like dotPeek or reflector) you can see how messy the array parsing code is for a similar array in JSON.  Granted this has to handle a much more varied array of tokens, but you get the idea.

Here is their `DeserializeList` implementation, uglier than it is normally as its dotPeek's decompiled version, not the original, but you get the idea.  The `DeserializeInternal` would recurse down to the child list.

```
private IList DeserializeList(int depth)
{
  IList list = (IList) new ArrayList();
  char? nullable1 = this._s.MoveNext();
  if (((int) nullable1.GetValueOrDefault() != 91 ? 1 : (!nullable1.HasValue ? 1 : 0)) != 0)
    throw new ArgumentException(this._s.GetDebugString(AtlasWeb.JSON_InvalidArrayStart));
  bool flag = false;
  char? nextNonEmptyChar;
  char? nullable2;
  do
  {
    char? nullable3 = nextNonEmptyChar = this._s.GetNextNonEmptyChar();
    if ((nullable3.HasValue ? new int?((int) nullable3.GetValueOrDefault()) : new int?()).HasValue)
    {
      char? nullable4 = nextNonEmptyChar;
      if (((int) nullable4.GetValueOrDefault() != 93 ? 1 : (!nullable4.HasValue ? 1 : 0)) != 0)
      {
        this._s.MovePrev();
        object obj = this.DeserializeInternal(depth);
        list.Add(obj);
        flag = false;
        nextNonEmptyChar = this._s.GetNextNonEmptyChar();
        char? nullable5 = nextNonEmptyChar;
        if (((int) nullable5.GetValueOrDefault() != 93 ? 0 : (nullable5.HasValue ? 1 : 0)) == 0)
        {
          flag = true;
          nullable2 = nextNonEmptyChar;
        }
        else
          goto label_8;
      }
      else
        goto label_8;
    }
    else
      goto label_8;
  }
  while (((int) nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() != 44 ? 1 : (!nullable2.HasValue ? 1 : 0)) == 0);
  throw new ArgumentException(this._s.GetDebugString(AtlasWeb.JSON_InvalidArrayExpectComma));
 label_8:
  if (flag)
    throw new ArgumentException(this._s.GetDebugString(AtlasWeb.JSON_InvalidArrayExtraComma));
  char? nullable6 = nextNonEmptyChar;
  if (((int) nullable6.GetValueOrDefault() != 93 ? 1 : (!nullable6.HasValue ? 1 : 0)) != 0)
    throw new ArgumentException(this._s.GetDebugString(AtlasWeb.JSON_InvalidArrayEnd));
  else
    return list;
}
```

Recursive parsing is just not managed as well though in C# as it is in F#.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real "standard" way of doing this. Note that the implementation can get pretty messy if you want to consider all possibilities. I would recommend something recursive like:

```
    private static IEnumerable<object> StringToArray2(string input)
    {
        var characters = input.GetEnumerator();
        return InternalStringToArray2(characters);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<object> InternalStringToArray2(IEnumerator<char> characters)
    {
        StringBuilder valueBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while (characters.MoveNext())
        {
            char current = characters.Current;

            switch (current)
            {
                case '[':
                    yield return InternalStringToArray2(characters);
                    break;
                case ']':
                    yield return valueBuilder.ToString();
                    valueBuilder.Clear();
                    yield break;
                case ',':
                    yield return valueBuilder.ToString();
                    valueBuilder.Clear();
                    break;
                default:
                    valueBuilder.Append(current);
                    break;
            }
```

Although your not restricted to recursiveness and can always fall back to a single method like

```
    private static IEnumerable<object> StringToArray1(string input)
    {
        Stack<List<object>> levelEntries = new Stack<List<object>>();
        List<object> current = null;
        StringBuilder currentLineBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char nextChar in input)
        {
            switch (nextChar)
            {
                case '[':
                    levelEntries.Push(current);
                    current = new List<object>();
                    break;
                case ']':
                    current.Add(currentLineBuilder.ToString());
                    currentLineBuilder.Clear();
                    var last = current;
                    if (levelEntries.Peek() != null)
                    {
                        current = levelEntries.Pop();
                        current.Add(last);
                    }
                    break;
                case ',':
                    current.Add(currentLineBuilder.ToString());
                    currentLineBuilder.Clear();
                    break;
                default:
                    currentLineBuilder.Append(nextChar);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return current;
    }
```

Whatever smells good to you

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO; //Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
using System.IO;

public class Sample {
    static void Main(){
        string data = "[a, b, [c, [d, e]], f, [g, h], i]";
        string[] fields = StringToArray(data);
        //check print
        foreach(var item in fields){
            Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"",item);
        }
    }
    static string[] StringToArray(string data){
        string[] fields = null;
        Regex innerPat = new Regex(@"\[\s*(.+)\s*\]");
        string innerStr = innerPat.Matches(data)[0].Groups[1].Value;
        StringBuilder wk = new StringBuilder();
        var balance = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i<innerStr.Length;++i){
            char ch = innerStr[i];
            switch(ch){
            case '[':
                if(balance == 0){
                    wk.Append('"');
                }
                wk.Append(ch);
                ++balance;
                continue;
            case ']':
                wk.Append(ch);
                --balance;
                if(balance == 0){
                    wk.Append('"');
                }
                continue;
            default:
                wk.Append(ch);
                break;
            }
        }
        var reader = new StringReader(wk.ToString());
        using(var csvReader = new TextFieldParser(reader)){
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] {","});
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            fields = csvReader.ReadFields();
        }
        return fields;
    }
}
```