# Can someone please help me find the regex if an input string is a valid xml string?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check for valid xml in string input before calling .LoadXml()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86292/how-to-check-for-valid-xml-in-string-input-before-calling-loadxml)

In a program I am implementing, user can input a string.
I have to identify that if it is a valid xml then I have to treat it differently.  Is there a regex that can find if a given string is a valid xml?

Comment: Why not try loading it into an XmlDocument or XDocument and looking for parse exceptions? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86292/how-to-check-for-valid-xml-in-string-input-before-calling-loadxml or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026247/check-well-formed-xml-without-a-try-catch or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490053/how-to-tell-if-a-string-is-xml

Comment: Regex is the *completely* wrong tool for that. It's like trying to build a skyscraper with a toothbrush. Even assuming you mean "well-formed", and not "valid" in the XML spec sense (i.e. both well-formed and conforming to a schema).

Comment: Maybe [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15100/checking-and-returning-xml-from-a-byte-array) can help!

Comment: I think you ought to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It is not possible to construct a "plain" regex to recognize strings with balanced parentheses from strings with unbalanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/335858), because the underlying programmable system of regex is not powerful enough to do it. For the same reason, it is theoretically impossible to construct a regular expression that could recognize a well-formed XML<sup>*</sup>.

Even if it were possible theoretically to construct such expression, it would not be practical: the amount of work needed to build a recognizer would be roughly the same as the amount of work needed to build a full-fledged XML parser.

Luckily, .NET comes with several XML parsers already. A piece of code like this

```
bool TryGetValidXml(string s, out XDoxument res) {
    try {
        res = XDocument.Load(s);
        return true;
    } catch {
        res = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

would do the trick.

---

<sup>*</sup> There are various extensions, such as Perl's [recursive regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4445674/335858) and .NET [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7973652/335858) that let you work around this limitation.

Comment: To avoid double work, I would add a `out XDocument validDocument` as parameter, to allow the caller to directly get the document, instead of first check, then parse, which would result in twice the parsing work

Comment: @SteveB You are right, this is a good idea. The OP is going to need that XML anyway, so there's no reason to throw away the parsed document.

Comment: I've submitted a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15100/checking-and-returning-xml-from-a-byte-array) in order to speed up the process, by having some preflight chekcs before the actual parsing.